# Vue HTML escape

Tags: xss

I have done a code scan and fail to understand whether there is a real problem. For both cases I get "Vue HTML escaping is disabled.".

- Case 1: `<a :href="return.url">` doesn't this simply embed the value of `return.url`? Is this vulnerable to a XSS?
- Case 2: `<span v-html="htmlTemp">` I read in the [Vue.js documentation](https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-directives.html#v-html) that `v-html` is potentially dangerous.

How would I mitigate it?

Comment: Welcome to the community. It would be essential to know the at least major version of Vue.js you're using and your approximate architecture

Comment: And also which Code Scanner did you use?

Comment: sounds like ":href" and "v-html" can be used to bypass Vue's escaping.  You shouldn't set those to any untrusted user-input.  (An attack could do things like steal/redirect locally stored values such as session tokens, passwords, etc...  or simply re-direct the user to phishing page or other malicious site.)  So where does "return.url" and "htmlTemp" come from?

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answers. So the vue version would be 3.3.8 and the architecture is a bit complex so I'm not sure whether user input used in those elements. I have done a bit more research and for the v-html element I now understand that it is there exactly to not escape anything. So potential user input would be dangerous.
The :href does also no escaping if I understand you correctly @browsermator?

Comment: Then I think the best I can do to be on the save side an use sanitize-url.
I just also found https://vuejs.org/guide/best-practices/security where both cases are described.

Comment: sanitize-url is not enough if these values are user-supplied.  You should never allow users to post links... if you need to allow that sort of thing you need to white-list specific URLs and be sure you specifically craft those... you'll probably want those links to go through a server you control that logs and checks white-list.  So you'd supply the URL... ex: https : //mydomain.com / urlchecker?url=some-harmless-base64-encoded-value-to-represent-user-submitted-url... then you can redirect the user if it passed your checks.  If an attack happens you'd flag/remove it from the whitelist.

Comment: @browsermator alright thank you a lot for your input. I think I have a clearer picture about this stuff now.